# How to encrypt php variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, encryption

When I creat a php variable in javascript, I use this method:

```
var jArray =  <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>;
```

It's very good but if i view the source code, ther is my full array in the script area.

My problem is that, my php array contains secret data, and I want to use this data in javascritp.

How can I hide from my sourc code, or what can I do?

I tride javascript obfuscation but it can't work with `<?php ?>` tag.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't hide anything with javascript, if you really want to try to hide it from your viewsource, do some ajax calls. But still it will never be secret.

Comment: To whom should this data be secret?

Comment: As above, nothing client side is secret. Any processing involving sensitive data should be done server side, with only the non sensative result returned to the client

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740164/encrypt-a-javascript-json-coming-from-a-php-array?rq=1

Comment: You could use AJAX to pass data from JavaScript to a PHP Skript