# How to secure ajax content

Tags: ajax, linux, apache, http, security

I was on almaconnect.com, on home page there is a textbox which auto-suggest some results of universities when you type (load content by making an ajax call). I did make a curl request of same ajax call but request resulted in some encrypted lines on terminal

```
curl 'https://www.almaconnect.com/suggestions/portaled_institute?q=am' -H 'Host: www.almaconnect.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: https://www.almaconnect.com/' -H 'Cookie: Almaconnect=; _ga=GA1.2.315358219.1489989532; __utma=117457241.315358219.1489989532.1490871434.1492414070.3; __utmz=117457241.1490871434.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _gat=1; __utmb=117457241.1.10.1492414070; __utmc=117457241; __utmt=1'
```

I want exactly the same functionality for my website so that if any user try to fetch my website data , he would not be able to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whatever binary data you see in the terminal when you make the curl call is not encrypted content. It is just compressed content. You can verify it by running

```
curl $params > output
```

You can check if the file matches any known file formats by running

```
file output
```

You will see that the result as something similar to

```
output: gzip compressed data, from Unix
```

Running `gzip -d -c output` will decompress and print the plaintext content to the terminal screen.

## Reason

The reason why this happens is because, you send the `accept-encoding` header with the curl call. Unlike the browser, curl does not decompress the result automatically. That is the reason for this confusion.

```
 -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'
```

Removing this particular header from the curl call will get you the response in an uncompressed plaintext format directly. You can try the following command for that.

```
curl 'https://www.almaconnect.com/suggestions/portaled_institute?q=am' -H 'Host: www.almaconnect.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: https://www.almaconnect.com/' -H 'Cookie: Almaconnect=; _ga=GA1.2.315358219.1489989532; __utma=117457241.315358219.1489989532.1490871434.1492414070.3; __utmz=117457241.1490871434.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _gat=1; __utmb=117457241.1.10.1492414070; __utmc=117457241; __utmt=1'
```

## Summary

almaconnect.com does not really take any extra steps to obfuscate their AJAX responses. And it is generally a bad idea to do so. Whatever method you employ to obfuscate your responses (like using HTTP Referrer field), people can always come up with counter-measures to defeat them.

It is simply not worth the time to put in effort and time to come up with a mechanism which would eventually be broken by a determined attacker.

Comment: Thank you @gtux , "accept encoding" was confusing me here , wonderfully explained.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

The [answer from gtux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43515051/1536382) well explains the reasons why you are seeing binary characters of compressed content, not of encrypted content.

Note that this very simple version works:

```
   curl 'https://www.almaconnect.com/suggestions/portaled_institute?q=am'
```

The answer [from gaganshera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43447295/1536382) may show you a way to obfuscate content, but that doesn't mean to really protect content, just to make a little harder for people to see it, since the decryption code is in public pages.

Your site can be protected by security (login + set cookie) or be public. If is protected, the security code checks the cookie header. If is public there are only ways to obfuscate content, not to protect it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570971/1536382

https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-hide-JSON-data-from-tools-like-Chrome-development-tools-and-Firebug-etc-as-a-security-beyond-https

Answer (score 0):

The server is returning an encrypted response which after its receipt is decrypted at the client end using javascript. You can do the same by sending your server response in some encryption that will be then decrypted at the client side. An example of the same can be crypto js.
Have a look at this: [Encrypt with PHP, Decrypt with Javascript (cryptojs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337317/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs)

Comment: but they are doing something differently cause if you see in firebug response is not encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are checking the HTTP_REFERER value for the ajax request. If the HTTP_REFERER is not the website, then it can return an encrypted response.

The ajax calls can also be secured using time based tokens. For example when a web page is requested, a random string may be generated on the server and stored in database. This string is sent to the client, which uses it in the ajax request. The server can then check if the token has expired or not. This method allows the ajax call to be valid for a certain time.

Comment: I am setting Referer in my curl request so that could not be a case.