# Regex for Masking Data in a JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, regex, splunk, data-masking

I've got a requirement to mask the incoming JSON request inside an array using regular expression on Splunk indexer. The JSON data looks like this:

```
{"Name":["Jobs","Bill"]}
```

I'm expected to mask the incoming data so that it looks like this:

```
{"Name":["******","******"]}
```

And the regex I'm using to mask the data looks something like this:

```
s/\"Name\":\"[^"]*\"/"Name":"******"/g
```

But for some reason I'm unable to mask the JSON data. Could any of you good folks please help?

Comment: This makes no sense. I'd suggest to read this: [Can I encrypt my JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570831/can-i-encrypt-my-json-data)

Comment: @MaciejLos, I skimmed through the link you've provided, but that isn't of much help in my case :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
s/(?:\G(?!^)\",|\"Name\":\[)\"\K[^\"]*/******/g
```

To support escaped `\"`, use

```
s/(?:\G(?!^)\",|\"Name\":\[)\"\K[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*/******/g
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/FuWmsa/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/FuWmsa/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)\",|\"Name\":\[)` - either the end of the previous match and then `",` substring, or `"Name":[` substring
- `\"` - `"` char
- `\K` - match reset  operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[^\"]*` - any zero or more chars other than `"`.
- `[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*` - any 0+ chars other than `"` and `\` and then zero or more repetitions of a `\` followed with any char but a line break char and then any 0+ chars other than `\` and `"`.

Comment: This did it!! Thank you very much!